# libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, compilation, g++

I know that a similar question has been asked before, but none of the suggestions have helped.

I am trying to compile an OpenCV project using C++ in Ubuntu 15.10.  I can run the project correctly in Netbeans.  But I am supposed to send this to someone who will be using the command line.  I can compile the program with the line:

```
 g++ -ggdb -o convert *.cpp  \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\`
```

Where `convert` is the chosen name for the executable.  There are no problems after executing this line.  But when I run

`./convert "image1.tif" "image2.tif"`

I get:

```
  ./convert: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In my .cpp files, I have:

```
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

The file `libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2` is in my `/usr/local/lib` folder.  I tried putting `-L/usr/local/lib` in the command line, but this did not help.  Perhaps this file path needs to go in a specific order in the command line?  The order mattered for the `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`, which had to come after the -o convert *.cpp.

Comment: I found the answer here:  

http://answers.opencv.org/question/6732/missing-shared-library/

I had to add:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
to the .bashrc file.

Answer (score 3):

Just for convenience, as the first comment said, you just need:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
```

if your `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`

Answer (score 1):

Your `libopencv_imgcodecs.so` isn't linked correctly. You can check that by using `ldd`:

```bash
$ ldd ./convert
/path/to/program/convert:
        ...
        libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_core.so.3.2 => not found
        ...
```

You can find where `libopencv_imgcodecs.so` is installed:

```bash
$ find / -type f -name libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2
```

Save this directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib
```